# Can someone explain why this require does not stop the function?

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

it might be simple but I am in the process of learning solidity.
In remix IDE, debugging a contract function, the function  starts with two requires:

```
 function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
    require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);    
    require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

    balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numTokens);
    allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
    balances[buyer] = balances[buyer].add(numTokens);
    emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
    return true;
}
```

The balance of the owner is OK but the allowed mapping is empty.

The locals are:

```
{
    "owner": {
        "value": "0x5B38DA6A701C568545DCFCB03FCB875F56BEDDC4",
        "type": "address"
    },
    "buyer": {
        "value": "0xAB8483F64D9C6D1ECF9B849AE677DD3315835CB2",
        "type": "address"
    },
    "numTokens": {
        "value": "1",
        "type": "uint256"
    },
    "<1>": {
        "value": false,
        "type": "bool"
    }
}
```

The state are:

```
{
    "name": {
        "length": "0x0",
        "raw": "0x",
        "type": "string",
        "value": "<constant>",
        "constant": true,
        "immutable": false
    },
    "symbol": {
        "length": "0x0",
        "raw": "0x",
        "type": "string",
        "value": "<constant>",
        "constant": true,
        "immutable": false
    },
    "decimals": {
        "value": "<constant>",
        "type": "uint8",
        "constant": true,
        "immutable": false
    },
    "balances": {
        "value": {
            "0000000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4": {
                "value": "7770999963",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            "000000000000000000000000ab8483f64d9c6d1ecf9b849ae677dd3315835cb2": {
                "value": "1",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
                "value": "32",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            "0000000000000000000000004b20993bc481177ec7e8f571cecae8a9e22c02db": {
                "value": "4",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        },
        "type": "mapping(address => uint256)",
        "constant": false,
        "immutable": false
    },
    "allowed": {
        "value": {},
        "type": "mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256))",
        "constant": false,
        "immutable": false
    },
    "totalSupply_": {
        "value": "7771000000",
        "type": "uint256",
        "constant": false,
        "immutable": false
    },
    "addressTable": {
        "value": {},
        "type": "mapping(string => address)",
        "constant": false,
        "immutable": false
    }
}
```

How can the second require passes and the status in Remix IDE terminal is *true Transaction mined and execution succeed*?

Comment: What is the question?
As per I understand the function should fail according to you but it is not failing, right?
Also, please paste the contract code, I can check on my remix and see what's happening.

Comment: @ZartajAfser you understood properly it should fail IMHO. The contract code I download as an example in my Remix project is https://etherscan.io/token/0xdacd69347de42babfaecd09dc88958378780fb62 and compiled it with the latest 0.6 version.

Comment: How much token are you sending?

Comment: 1 as shown by the locals I have pasted in the question @ZartajAfser

Comment: Can you log `allowed[owner][msg.sender]`? It should be zero but if require didn't fail then perhaps it is some other value. I don't trust the visualization tools if the data is complicated they might fail.

Comment: Using hardhat `console.log`, I  can log: ```console.log:
allowed[owner][msg.sender] :
100``` while still having an empty mapping: ```"allowed": {
  "value": {},
  "type": "mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256))",
  "constant": false,
  "immutable": false
 }``` so I have to conclude you are right. But what a tricking debugging tool! Thank you @Ismael

Answer (score 0):

make sure before calling this function you approved the address you want to be able to spend your tokens, if you are using openZeppelin ERC20 contracts it has approve function which you can call if not create it your self and update the mapping with address and the amount of tokens you want to allow

Comment: That is what I understood but why the approved mapping empty? Even if I call the approve function (https://etherscan.io/token/0xdacd69347de42babfaecd09dc88958378780fb62). But why is the call not reverted if the approve state is `{}`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out thanks to [@Ismael's comment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150513/can-someone-explain-why-this-require-does-not-stop-the-function?noredirect=1#comment168555_150513).

> Can you log allowed[owner][msg.sender]? It should be zero but if require didn't fail then perhaps it is some other value. I don't trust the visualization tools if the data is complicated they might fail.

The issue is coming from the tool RemixIDE, as confirmed by the log being different, [see my comment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150513/can-someone-explain-why-this-require-does-not-stop-the-function#comment169570_150513).

By using [hardhat console.log](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/debugging-with-hardhat-network#solidity--console.log), I logged the value of `allowed[owner][msg.sender]` and it was 100, since this is more than the value I was providing to the function as `numTokens`, the require statement was passing.

Console logging values to ensure they match what you expect them to be is a powerful debugging method that can help you figure out why your code doesn't behave as you want it to.